# startActivityForResult is not run

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, crop

why `onActivityResult` is not run ? 
can anybody help?
i have only on class name is `MainActivity`
This is my code

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity{

public static final int CROP = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
private ImageView imgView;
private Button selectBtn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    hasilET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hasilET);
    selectBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new ClickSelect());

}
public class ClickSelect implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "CLICK");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("image/*");
        i.putExtra("crop", "true");
        i.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        i.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        i.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        i.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        i.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(i, CROP);            
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Log.v(TAG, "crop");
        Bitmap bmp;
        if(requestCode==1){
            if(data != null){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                bmp = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);                    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Jsut after taking a quick look at your code:

Seems correct, what happens if you replace your CROP in

```
startActivityForResult(i, CROP);
```

with a number? an use the same number in

```
  if(requestCode==CROP)
```

and maybe remove this line:

```
 i.putExtra("crop", "true")
```

Comment: i have change that with 1, but still not run, can you help me?

Comment: did you try it without the  i.putExtra("crop", "true") - thats what broke mine a while :D

Comment: when debug without i.putExtra("crop", "true"), there is no crop interface. i think something wrong with `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onActivityResult()` in your `MainActivity` class

Move `onActivityResult()` from class `ClickSelect` to `MainActivity`

Use this example: [Example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == CROP) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is the error when i Override onActivityResult: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) of type MainActivity.ClickSelect must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java /PETIv2/src/com/petiv2 line 110 Java Problem

Comment: Move onActivityResult() from class ClickSelect to MainActivity

Comment: its not work, void is an invalid type for the variabel onActivityResult. error again

Comment: how can use intent in single class ?

Comment: post ur MainActivity and i will take a look at it. At any rate, your onActivityResult should not be inside public class ClickSelect implements View.OnClickListener {}. It should be part of MainActivity which extends Activity base class. Is you gallery launching when you click on the button, at least?

Comment: ok. two mistakes. u don't need to class ClickSelect at all. just make MainActivity implement the View.OnClickListener. And then override onActivityResult. Note that onActivityResult is "protected void" and not "public void".

Comment: look at some examples on the internet. there are plenty. but that's your problem - having onActivityResult inside of ClickSelect rather than inside MainActivity.